# Почему свой бывает "в доску"?

Tags: фразеология

О простом, общительном человеке говорят, что он "свой в доску". А почему, собственно, "в доску"?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?bukv=%D1&id=7.18&page=1&wrd=%D1%E2%EE%E9%20%E2%20%E4%EE%F1%EA%F3
    "Свой в доску - свой целиком и полностью.
 Если вспомнить фразеологизмы "до гробовой доски" (= до самого конца) или             "прочесть от доски до доски" (= от начала до конца), то можно интерпретировать   выражение "свой в доску" как "свой целиком и полностью, от начала до конца, до самой гробовой доски"."

Answer (score 2):

Помнится, смысл этого выражения выводили из плотницкого жаргона. 
"Свой в доску" - подогнанный, совпадающий как доски в столешнице.

(Столешница здесь крышка стола, а не современная мебель из камня и металла).